# What is the difference between delete and block user from a list?

Tags: manual-testing, user-acceptance-testing

What is the difference between delete and block user from a list?

Suppose I am testing a community which has delete and block a user. Both of these options now what should the expected result should be for both of them right now in both cases the user is being deleted/blocked from the community.

Comment: I'm voting to close; this isn't something we can answer.  It's up to your designers/developers/stakeholders to define what deleting and blocking users means.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the design document, each application may have different definitions of "delete" and "block".

P.S.: It is not entirely clear whether you are testing from an admin point of view or a client point of view.

For example:

- As a client, I can delete/remove someone from my contact list, you can take a look at LinkedIn's definition of [Removing a Connection](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/49/removing-a-connection?lang=en), which is similar to delete.
- As a client, I can block someone too, please look at LinkedIn's definition of [Blocking](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/2839).
- Exactly what an admin can do with delete and block is not always public information. In general, an admin has a higher privilege than a user. Again, you must refer to the exact design document for more details.

Comment: Thanx a lot and in this case I am testing as an admin point of view

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the specific software you are testing, but generally a blocked user still has some form of information (account details) in the system, they just cannot access the system. A deleted user would have all of their account details removed from the database.

In other words, it's the difference between "You are not allowed to view this content" and "You do not have an account, would you like to create one?".

Answer (score 0):

In software, We have seen the block and delete functionality. Basically, bothe functionality is used for a stop to system access.

But still, both are the difference.

**Block :**

- Block functionality is useful for blocking the user.
- Once the user is blocked then he/she can not access the system.
- If the admin can wish him to live then he can set as him to active.

**Delete:**

- Delete functionality is useful to delete the user or any other data.
- Once we delete the record then we can not see that record into our system.
- In software, We have to delete record as two type.

  1. **Hard delete:** If we have deleted the data also from the database then its called as hard delete.
  2. **Soft delete**: If we have delete data from the only system then its called as soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context in which you are testing this.

Before deriving any scenario, ensure that:

- Understanding the functionality for **BLOCK** and **DELETE** Users from business/end user perspective is clear.
- Deriving the normal happy flow scenarios - Ex: If I **BLOCK** a user then his access to the system should be restricted and until the user gets UNBLOCKED. For **DELETE** - Here the user gets restricted removed permanently and should not be able to access the system
- Other scenarios: like - **UNBLOCK** the blocked user and check whether user is able to access the system
- Delete the unblocked user who just got unblocked - ensure user should not be able to access the system
- Verify that the deleted users should never appear on the list (again depends on the context)
- Verify blocked users appear on the list with no access to system
- Verify those users in the list, who are neither BLOCKED nor DELETED should have access to system
- Try to add the **DELETED** user back to the list (like re-enrollment - depends on business requirement) - appears on list and able to access the system - Perform BLOCK functionality on this re-enrolled user and verify the functionality

The list of scenarios goes on....
*As mentioned it purely depends on the business/end-user and in what context you are testing this functionality*